# Foreach to concatenate DLG and GG groups for Active Directory

Tags: powershell, foreach, active-directory

I'd like the script to get contents from a text file and add DLG, GG to the front of each line.

For example

```
IT
Fiance
HR
```

should be changed into

```
DLG IT, GG IT
DLG Fiance, GG Fiance
DLG HR, GG HR
```

I then would like to create a `foreach` loop to create a Domain Local Group and a Global Group and make the GG group a member of the DLG Group.

I've tried 3 different variations to concatenate, but none of them seem to work.

Version 1

```
Get-Content ".\Groups.txt" | ForEach-Object ($name) {
    $DLGGROUP = '"DLG"+" "+$Name'
    $GGGROUP = '"GG"+" "+$Name'
    "$DLGGROUP, $GGGROUP" | Out-File -filepath ".\DLGGG.csv"
}
```

Version 2

```
foreach ($name in Get-Content ".\Groups.txt") {
    $DLGGROUP = "DLG" + " " + $Name
    $GGGROUP = "GG" + " " + $Name
    "$DLGGROUP, $GGGROUP" | Out-File -filepath ".\DLGGG.csv"
}
```

Version 3

```
$name = (Get-Content ".\Groups.txt")
foreach ($name in $groups) {
    $DLGGROUP = "DLG" + " " + $Name
    $GGGROUP = "GG" + " " + $Name
    "$DLGGROUP, $GGGROUP" | Out-File -filepath ".\DLGGG.csv"
}
```

Comment: Version 2 should work. What is its actual output? Version 1 doesn't work b/c you used single-quoted strings (PowerShell doesn't expand variables in those). Version 3 doesn't work b/c you re-used the variable with the content of the file as the loop variable.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, version 2 only leaves me the gives me the last pair of variables

DLG HR, GG HR

I think what is happening is it just recreates the csv files multiple times instead of adding to it?

Comment: Ok worked it out just use add-content

Comment: Alternatively use `Out-File -Append`.